# How can I configure cron startup on a new image without harming the Apache service?

Tags: docker

I'm creating a new image with cron which is based on the `php:7.3-apache-buster` image.

The build of the image goes without a hitch. The container is also created with a status of Up. However, in the browser when I type `http://localhost:8082` no Apache page is shown. The Apache service is inherited from the `php:7.3-apache-buster` image.

In my Dockerfile the last line is `CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log`. I believe it is this line that generates the problem.

If I enter the container with the command `docker exec -it cont-mysite-01 /bin/bash` and run the command `service apache2 start`, Apache starts normally.

What am I not understanding?

How can I build an image where the Apache from the base image and the Cron from the new image work together?

My references:

https://github.com/Ekito/docker-cron/blob/master/Dockerfile

https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

I removed the line `CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log` from the Dockerfile.

Then I added the line `RUN sed -i 's/^exec /service cron start\n\nexec /' /usr/local/bin/apache2-foreground`.

After creating the container with the image run the commands to check Apache2 and Cron:

`docker exec -it cont-mysite-01 service apache2 status`

`docker exec -it cont-mysite-01 service cron status`

Link that helped me:

http://www.idein.it/joomla/14-docker-php-apache-with-crontab